# executing script using ssh inside a loop

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to write a script, where I have a loop to login to multiple remote machines and execute a script inside each machine. Here is an example:

```
for ((j=1; j < 2; j++)); do 

  mchname="n"$j

  ssh -T $mchname <<'ENDSSH'    
    ./run_script < input > output &    
  ENDSSH

done
```

Whenever I try to execute the above script I get:
"warning: here-document at line 37 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `ENDSSH')"

I am new to ssh, so I am sure I am making a silly mistake. Can anyone suggest me a solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

There's a problem in your bash script. The heredoc end tag (ENDSSH in your script) cannot be indented.

Try this instead:

```
  ssh -T $mchname <<'ENDSSH'    
    ./run_script < input > output &    
ENDSSH
# ^ no indentation for that line
```

**Edit:**

Also, you can run a command on the remote system by passing it as an argument to ssh, rather than providing it as standard input.  The command will be executed by the user's remote shell:

```
ssh -T $mchname './run_script < input > output &'
```

Comment: And `-T` is the default when you give `ssh` an explicit command to run, so `ssh $mchname './run_script < input > output &'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have never caught that!

Comment: If you use '<<-' instead of '<<' for the here document, any leading tabs (just tabs, not arbitrary whitespace) from the here document and the end tag will be stripped, allowing you to indent them more naturally.